The condition of compactness of subgroup of infinite Galois group
Question: Let $E$ be Galois over $F$, with Galois group $G$. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Prove that $H$ is dense in $G$ if and only if for any subfield $K$ of $E$ containing $F$ and $K$ finite and Galois over $F$, $H/(H \cap Gal(E/K)) \cong Gal(K/F)$.
My attempt is as follows. One theorem of infinite Galois theory says that $Gal(E/E^H)$ is the closure of $H$. Therefore that $H$ is dense in $G$ is equivalent to $Gal(E/E^H) = Gal(E/F)$. This means that $H=G$ if $H$ is closed(obviously). But what to do if $H$ is not closed?
I am quite confused about what can be done in an infinite Galois extension.
I appreciate any help you can provide.
